# Pandas copy previous day's data based on key and date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe in Pandas. I want to roll/copy the data for the missing dates withing the start/end dates.

I want to create rows for 3-MAR-21 and 4-MAR-21 as per below ---

For 3-MAR-21, all the three loans L1, L2 and L3 rows should be copied from 2-MAR-21

For 4-MAR-21, only L1 and L3 should be copied, because L2 ends on 3-MAR-21.

| DATE | Loan ID | Stat Date | End Date | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-MAR-21 | L1 | 1-MAR-21 | 10-MAR-21 | 100 |
| 1-MAR-21 | L2 | 1-MAR-21 | 3-MAR-21 | 150 |
| 1-MAR-21 | L3 | 1-MAR-21 | 31-MAR-21 | 160 |
| ---- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2-MAR-21 | L1 | 1-MAR-21 | 10-MAR-21 | 110 |
| 2-MAR-21 | L2 | 1-MAR-21 | 3-MAR-21 | 160 |
| 2-MAR-21 | L3 | 1-MAR-21 | 31-MAR-21 | 170 |
| ---- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5-MAR-21 | L1 | 1-MAR-21 | 10-MAR-21 | 90 |
| 5-MAR-21 | L3 | 1-MAR-21 | 31-MAR-21 | 140 |

Update: Added more details

Comment: There is no `4-MAR-21` in your example data.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Updated question, I want to create 3-MAR-21 and 4-MAR-21 rows

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```py
# 4-MAR-21
rows = df.loc[df['DATE'] == '2-MAR-21, :]
rows['DATE] = '3-MAR-21'
df = df.append(rows, ignore_index=True)

# 5-MAR-21
rows = df.loc[
    (df["DATE"] == "2-MAR-21") & ((df["Loan ID"] == "L1") | (df["Loan ID"] == "L3")), :
]
rows["DATE"] = "4-MAR-21"
df = df.append(rows, ignore_index=True)

# Sort values
df = df.sort_values(by=["DATE"], ascending=True, inplace=False)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried to solve this by multiple google search and it looks to give correct results, posting if someone else has similar need.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import numpy as np
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)


data = {
  "DATE": ['3/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/2/2021', '3/2/2021', '3/2/2021', '3/5/2021', '3/5/2021'],
  "LOAN_ID": ['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L1', 'L3'],
    "START_DATE": ['3/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/1/2021'],
    "END_DATE": ['3/10/2021', '3/3/2021', '3/31/2021', '3/10/2021', '3/3/2021', '3/31/2021', '3/10/2021', '3/31/2021'],
    "RATE": ['100', '150', '160', '110', '160', '170', '90', '140']
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
df.END_DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.END_DATE)
print(df)
# Date range
start_date = date(2021, 3, 1)
end_date = date(2021, 3, 15)
# variable to hold prev date
prev_date = date(2021, 3, 1)
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    # if date is found in dataset, don't do anything, don't know how to write inverse condition
    if (df.DATE == pd.Timestamp(single_date)).any():
        pass
    else:
        #print(single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") +  " :: " + prev_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))        
        # get previous day's rows
        df_prev = df[df['DATE'].dt.date == pd.Timestamp(prev_date)]
        # filter by end date
        df_filtered = df_prev[df_prev['END_DATE'].dt.date >= pd.Timestamp(single_date)]        
        #print(df_filtered)
        # replace DATE with missing date
        df_filtered['DATE'] =  pd.Timestamp(single_date)
        #print(df_filtered)
        # append dataset
        df=df.append(df_filtered, ignore_index=True)
        #print(df)
        
    prev_date = single_date

df.sort_values(by=['DATE'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

[image: Initial Dataset]
[image: New dataset]